# jQuery append item to every div + display it's ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-append

I am trying to append a button to every div with a certain class, my code so far is:

HTML:

```
<div id="865" class="gw-gopf-isotope-item">
 <div class="gw-gopf-post-overlay-inner">
  // button goes here
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".gw-gopf-isotope-item" ).each(function() {
 var gallid = $(this).attr('id');
 $('.gw-gopf-post-overlay-inner').append('<a class=\"gw-gopf-btn gw-gopf-post-overlay-btn thickbox\" href=\"#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=gallery-\"+gallid+\"\">View Photos</a>');
});
```

The way it works is:

- user creates a gallery in an admin
- these are displayed on the frontend
- another script I wrote creates a thickbox of content unique to each gallery
- the button is meant to link to that unique thickbox

The append code works fine but it doesn't generate the unique ID for each link hence why I think I need to use the each function?

I have to do this with jQuery as it's amending a pre-built system which I can't modify to add the code in directly.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a4zh87jg/4/ This one is correct with your code, and works!

Comment: If it still does not work, maybe it is your // in the html which is not a correct comment style for html!

Comment: Is jquery used at all? can you print anything to the console? Do you have an onready event? How is the code triggered. As you can see in the fiddle, it works!

Comment: I can write to console outside of the each function, and jQuery is loaded fine (there are other jquery things running).

I can see your code works and something on my end is blocking it, just need to work out what :)

Comment: Then your question has been answered I guess. Check for any other JS errors then. How do you find the initial parent div? You could access these div also in the manner I did in the original fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a4zh87jg/ see the wrapping "anchor" div as entry!

Comment: Are the items generated on the fly? And are you in a dom ready state to set the id? Then you might need to use .on() to get you going. Here is the jquery doc http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Gareth be so kind and accept my answer, as it does answer your jquery question!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `'` as a dilimiter and escaping  quotations `\"`, you are missing two times `'` around `'+gallid+'`

It should be:

```
$('.gw-gopf-post-overlay-inner').append('<a class=\"gw-gopf-btn gw-gopf-post-overlay-btn thickbox\" href=\"#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=gallery-'+gallid+'\">View Photos</a>');
```

If you are still not getting an id debug it.

You can see if the `gallid` is generated by sending it to the console with console.log(gallid); within the .each loop

```
$( ".gw-gopf-isotope-item" ).each(function() {
 var gallid = $(this).attr('id');
 console.log(gallid);
...

});
```

**Look at this fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/a4zh87jg/4/ This one is correct with your code!

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason the actual button isn't being added to the div, that is my main focus of the question, is my each function wrong?

and gallid isn't being added to the console log either (but not worried about that just yet)

Comment: Yes it is! Give me a second!

Comment: Is jquery used at all? can you print anything to the console?

Comment: The items are created using Isotope so could that be the reason for this not working? I have done loads of different checks and it won't work at all within an each function but if I have the append by itself it works fine but obviously can't set the ID for the link.

Comment: Gareth, I know little about isotope, and this question is obviously about jquery. I also do not know your setup and whether you call a function from outside another script or where your data is coming from. Maybe that is for another question. But for your question above it works in jquery for the rest it's poking in the dark, and maybe you should ask another question regarding isotope.